# Azure CLI commands not working inside azure function apps (portal)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-function-app

I have powershell scripts which is running locally.But those scripts not running insite function apps > powershell (windows) machine.

> az login --service-principal -u $ServicePrincipalId -p
>   $ServicePrincipalPass --tenant $ServicePrincipalTenant

Getting below when i run the script

```
ERROR: The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

since i dont have az cli installed in the windows machine,  i have added below line to install az command in my script.

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber  -Scope CurrentUser
```

Getting access issue while installing the az.

```
2019-06-11T12:42:59.698 [Warning] WARNING: InternalWebProxy: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\2.0.12507\32bit\workers\powershell\runtimes\win-x86\lib\netcoreapp2.1\ref'.
2019-06-11T12:42:59.843 [Warning] WARNING: Win32Helpers: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\2.0.12507\32bit\workers\powershell\runtimes\win-x86\lib\netcoreapp2.1\ref'.
2019-06-11T12:43:05.023 [Warning] WARNING: User declined to install module (Az).
```

even -Force is not working. need to know what is causing the issue.

Note :- The script is perfectly running in local windows machine. the issue is when try to run on portal > functionapp> timertrigger

Attaching azure function app creating with windows machine

[image]

Getting error after adding cli folder into kudu

```
> 2019-06-13T12:29:40.510 [Error] ERROR:   File
> "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-68v0_w99\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 523, in execute Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Rpc.RpcException :
> Result: ERROR:   File
> "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-68v0_w99\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 523, in execute Exception:   File
> "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-68v0_w99\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 523, in execute
```

kudu console

[image]

Comment: I believe you are trying to run a az cli command. Installing az module does not install the az executable that you are trying to run.
The solution to this is installing az cli.
Use https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows to get the msi for az

Comment: it is running perfectly fine in local... but not in azure functions app, portal

Comment: The command you used to install the Azure CLI is not correct. It's used to install the Azure PowerShell. So it means you do nothing to install the Azure CLI.

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand the requirement. Are you looking to execute azure cli commands for operations on function apps ? this link might give you more context on that - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp?view=azure-cli-latest. If not, are you trying to execute a azure cli command with in a timetrigger based function app ? and why windows machine was getting in to the picture ? Can you please share any screen shots you might have so that it would better understand your scenario. Thanks

Comment: Also see if this link helps you.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell. Thanks

Comment: @bharathn-msft i am having script which has az commands. which i am running in windows machine which is in preview mode..

Comment: @bharathn-msft attached image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error shows that you do not install the Azure CLI in the environment. To install the Azure CLI, a possible way is to copy the whole CLI directory that you installed in the local machine to your function KUDU path `/home`.

In the test, the copy path in the function KUDU is `D:/home/CLI2/`.

Test code:

```
D:/home/CLI2/wbin/az.cmd login --service-principal -u 'xxxxxx' -p 'xxxxxx' --tenant 'xxxxxx' | Write-Host
```

The screenshot of the output:

[image]

Comment: getting error after adding cli folder to kudu.. is something i am missing here?-- i have added the error in the question block.

Comment: @pappu_kutty Where do you copy the folder? And which CLI folder do you copy? And what is the script you want to run?

Comment: i have copied folder inside D:home .. i have cli from my local as you mentioned. and i am running this script D:/home/CLI2/wbin/az.cmd login --service-principal -u $ServicePrincipalId -p $ServicePrincipalPass --tenant $ServicePrincipalTenant

Comment: @pappu_kutty How do you set the variables? And do you just run the script one time? Try more times. I assume that why the error shows the file exception in path "C:".

Comment: i run through function app timer trigger, even i tried in kudu console, it is not working. please check this link, which i have raised https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1246

Comment: @pappu_kutty Do you copy the whole CLI directory to the kubu path /home? not just the CLI2/wbin/az.cmd. And can you show the PowerShell script you use?

Comment: yes i copied whole path into kudu/Cli directory, i have attached the image for your reference

Comment: i ran in cmd and powershell in kudu console.. geting below error. ERROR: The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
ERROR: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-68v0_w99\knack\knack\cli.py", line 206, in invoke

Comment: @pappu_kutty The error seems you install the CLI through the pip? Or there is a path set in the environment?

Comment: @pappu_kutty Maybe there is an unexpected error. The final way, recreate your function and do the steps again.

Comment: @pappu_kutty No screen share. We just can talk in the SO. So the chat is OK.

Comment: i have drag and dropped cli folders in kudu

Comment: @pappu_kutty That is one way. But it would interrupt if it continues too long. So I suggest you compress the directory and upload it. Then decompress it in the kudu.

Comment: @pappu_kutty Yes, there is a lot of files in the CLI directory. But Azure CLI is not installed in the function environment. If you want to use it, you need to copy it yourself.

Comment: it is working, after i copied zip and dropping in kudu console.. you rock!!!!. i did manual copy,, which i missed few files...

Comment: @pappu_kutty Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested here, you need to install this:

https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows

In my case, I just had a corrupted installation of the Azure Client, and repairing it solved my issue.

ps. close your Powershell window before it