# How to run Azure CLI command from azure ADF pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory, azure-cli

I have set of Azure CLI commands ready which append data into an existing azure data lake file.

We need to run all these commands from an ADF (Azure Data Factory) pipeline. Does anyone have any idea on how we can run Azure CLI commands from ADF pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an Azure function and call it from ADF with the Azure Function Activity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity

Here is a tutorial to run azure-cli commands in Azure Functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/scripts/functions-cli-create-serverless

Hope this helped!!

Comment: Yes Martin, This post will help me.The second link which you mention is use to how to create azure function using CLI command. But I need How we write azure cli commands inside Azure function body?

Comment: Martin I get the details like how can we add cli commands inside azure function using this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56544059/azure-cli-commands-not-working-inside-azure-function-apps-portal