# The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

Created Powershell Azure function and trying to use "az" commands under that function app. As per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell#dependency-management), function runtime should resolve "az" and other module dependencies. but it doesn't work for me.

> ERROR: The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Rpc.RpcException : Result: ERROR: The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I want to run some "az" command under function app without manually uploading modules. Is it powershell Preview version issue or something I need to correct?

**requirement.psd1**

```
@{
Az = '2.*'
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you mean the Azure CLI, you can take a look at the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56544059/azure-cli-commands-not-working-inside-azure-function-apps-portal).

Comment: If I will copy CLI directory, probably it will work. then what is the use of requirement.psd1?

Comment: PLEASE do not post **_pictures_** of code, errors, or sample data. why should anyone be forced to squint at your image when _you already have it as text_. also, why force those who want to help you to type in the test code _when you already have it as text_.

Comment: First of all, Azure CLI is not the PowerShell module for the function. So you can not install the CLI module like the PowerShell modules nomally.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

"[Az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.6.0)" in the context of PowerShell probably means the Az module, with cmdlets like `Add-AzAccount` etc.

"[az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)" is the cross-platform CLI, which is not a PowerShell module.

Answer (score 51):

For those who get these error in local while trying to access AZ, try this command below in an *admin* PowerShell instance.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows -OutFile .\AzureCLI.msi; Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I AzureCLI.msi /quiet'; rm .\AzureCLI.msi
```

You can get more details about installation @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?view=azure-cli-latest&tabs=azure-powershell

**Make sure you restart the powershell instance**

Comment: Exactly what was needed! Thanks
(do not forget to reload the shell)

Comment: NOTE: You have to do this in an *admin* PowerShell instance (as mentioned at the link). I ran it in a user instance without luck, but running it in an admin shell worked like a charm.

Comment: Restart PowerShell after running this command so it updates all the changes done.

Comment: ~Make sure to restart the powershell~ is quite important!

Comment: I think people should be restarting powershell after this

Answer (score 31):

I got this error because I had not installed CLI.  I was sent this link which downloaded the required install:

https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows

Comment: I had installed the 64-bit version, and apparently this 32-bit version was expected. (Or perhaps there was just something wrong with my previous installation, but I used the equivalent 64-bit installer.) Installing from that link worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Two ways you can solve this issue.

Install below installation file for **Azure CLI** in windows.

https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows

**(OR)**

Install using **PowerShell** the below command.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows -OutFile .\AzureCLI.msi; Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I AzureCLI.msi /quiet'; rm .\AzureCLI.msi
```

More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?view=azure-cli-latest&tabs=azure-cli

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this really worked for me. Note - This required PowerShell to be open in Administrator mode

Answer (score 0):

I can see PowerShell 7.x and later is the recommended version.

You can check Powershell version using below command

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-6.2.0

**NOTE**

> PowerShell 7.x and later is the recommended version of PowerShell for
> use with the Azure Az PowerShell module on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Run the commands below to fix the issue:

```
Install-Module AzureAD -Force
Install-module AzureADPreview -Force
Install-Module -Name MSOnline -Force
Import-Module Az -Force
Install-Module Az -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

Download this then this problem will not occur.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).