# az login is giving "issuer" error when trying to login for authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, command-line-interface, azure-cli, kudu

I have installed Azure cli in KUDU. I saw the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56544059/azure-cli-commands-not-working-inside-azure-function-apps-portal). I tried using az login with service principal, secret and tenant, i am getting **issuer** error. I am not sure what exactly it is expecting.Here is the image of the Error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib7FT.png Is there any other way to login? Can anyone help me out here?

**Note**: My account has **MFA**. Not sure if this impacts az login command.

Comment: I dont think you can login headlessly with mfa